# How can I read a txt file line by line and print a specific object from that line? c#

Tags: c#

Example txt file.

> Main 98767 92,2838  923989382
> dog  cat -123  9838
> jason main data form print

Someone can help me how can read specific object from each line.
For example the output:
Main 922838
dog cat
data print

Comment: The easiest way is to use: `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what kind of objects would you like to create and what is the object separator. If the list of strings is good enough and the separator is space, here is a code snippet...

```
static void Main()
{
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;
        var objects = line.Split(' ').ToList();
        objects.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    }
}
```